Cryptomatte node does not recognise Cryptomatte layers in EXR file
Blender version: 4.1
I render to EXR then denoise specific passes and output Multilayer EXR again with File Output node and Cryptomatte layers copied. When I import this new image sequence for compositing, Cryptomatte node does not recognize Cryptomatte layers anymore. It works with Legacy node just fine, but I want to use viewport compositing, because it's a few orders of magnitude faster.
How do I output Cryptomatte layers with File Output node so that they work?

Took me a while to figure this out, but apparently Cryptomatte node does not work with EXR PIZ compression(the only one I tested). I initially rendered uncompressed (because it crashes after each render before saving otherwise) and I did use compression during denoising step, because it works fine then.
If I don't use compression for EXR output, Cryptomatte works fine.
Load times seem to increase with uncompressed files(mine are 2GB+ each) so it seems to be slower to switch frames, but the images are uncompressed in GPU memory anyway, so at least that is the same and it's possible to work with viewport compositor.
It could be worth to output only Cryptomate layers uncompressed and compress other passes for compositing.
